# Unable to install an Distribution build Flutter app .ipa ( Failed using apple configurator 2 and even on TestFlight app release)

Tags: ios, flutter, ipa

I am working on a flutter project and trying to release an IPA but if fails. I usually release on TestFlight but yesterday it failed, (I released one build successfully on last Friday).

When I create a development build IPA and try to install on my iPhone using Application Loader, it works fine.
But with a Distribution build it fails on installing iPA using ApplicationLoader.
With TestFlight, the app is released, it can be installed but on launching it crashes.

I have tried Flutter clean,Pod install, clearing all Derived data.
My certificates are valid.
The only thing that is changed from last Friday is I had Flutter upgrade to version 1.17.

I created build using this too..

```
flutter clean
rm -rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework
flutter build ios --release
```

But still not working when I try to install using application loader.

[image]

Please help! thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you able to get this resolved?

Comment: Yes, it is resolved. It was my mistake.  
1. Issue in TestFlight build from Ci/CD
- It was because of the difference in flutter version at Ci/CD endpoint and in my code. I had updated Flutter version at my end, but forgot to update Ci/CD flutter version.

2. Issue with App Configurator
- I generally work on Enterprise apps and I though I can install a distribution build using AppConfigurator, but that was my bad. It's not possible to install distribution build without Testflight or without AppStore.